# I remember reading a book a few years ago about boy transported to a alien world, need help finding

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember reading a book years ago about a young man or boy with a bad arm or hand moves somewhere new(I think different country) finds a some thing that transports him to a new(alien) world.

Other details I remember are, on the alien world he meets a girl(not necessarily completely human).

In the first few chapters the young man or boy with a bad arm or hand, filled a cake with laxatives that was eaten by the apartments building owners kid

The young man was also accompanied by another young man or boy he just met to the other world.

I remember in the next book the alien girl comes with them back to earth and the government sends agents to investigate the thing that transported them to a new world.

The alien world I think was having a war.

Thank you any help.

Comment: Very few people read the science fiction sequel to *Johnny Tremaine*. Even fewer than read the SF sequel to *101 Dalmations*. (Half of the preceding is a joke, the other's not).

Answer (score 5):

That would be 'The Lighthouse Trilogy' by Adrian McKinty beginning with 'The Lighthouse Land' in which a young Cancer survivor, and amputee moves to Muck Island in Ireland and finds there is more to his new home than he could have known.

An excerpt from the description of the book as found on Google.

> "Cancer has left Jamie without an arm or the will to speak. But Muck Island offers more than solitude and sea views. Jamie learns that he is heir to an ancient title, Laird of Muck, Guardian of the Passage, and certain otherworldly responsibilities. With the help of a mysterious object he discovers in the island's old lighthouse, Jamie sets out on a dangerous mission that will change the course of his life, and possibly the universe, forever."

Comment: Can you provide any details that suggest similarity? Maybe a synopsis or a few snippets of text?